# Satisfying two condition in one regex pattern in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am not sure if I have put the question right.

I want to satisfy both the text with one regular expression.

```
text1 = 'foobar';
text2 = 'foobar-baz';
```

Expected Output of **text1**

`$1` should be `bar`
`$2` should be `''`

Expected Output of **text2**

`$1` should be `bar`
`$2` should be `baz`

Here is what I have tried:

`/foo([a-z0-9\-_=\+\/]+)(\-(.*))?/i`

result for `text1` is correct but for `text2`, `$1` gets the full string `foobar-baz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is due to the possible inclusion of `-` in the first capturing group. There are 2 cases:

- There are one or more `-` in the string, and you want to pick the last group delimited by the hyphen. Intuitively, we think of greedy quantifier, and a simple solution like:

  ```
  input.match(/foo([a-z0-9_=+\/-]+)-(.*)/)
  ```

  would work.
- However the second case, where there are no `-` in the string, combined with the previous case, causes problem.

  Since `[a-z0-9_=+\/-]+` contains `-`, if you make `-(.*)` optional, given an input in the first case, it will just match to the end of the string and put everything in the first capturing group.

We need to control the backtracking behavior so that when there is at least one `-`, it must match it and match the last one, and allow the first group to gobble up everything when there is no `-`.

One solution which makes minimal change to your current regex is:

```
input.match(/foo([a-z0-9_=+\/-]+?)(?:-([a-z0-9_=+\/]*))?$/)
```

The lazy quantifier makes the engine tries from the left-most `-` first, and the anchor `$` and the character class without `-` at the end forces the engine to split only at the last `-` if any.

Note that the second capturing group will be `undefined` when there is no `-`.

Sample input output:

```
'foogoobarbaz'.match(/foo([a-z0-9_=+\/-]+?)(?:-([a-z0-9_=+\/]*))?$/)
> [ "foogoobarbaz", "goobarbaz", undefined ]
'foogoobar-baz'.match(/foo([a-z0-9_=+\/-]+?)(?:-([a-z0-9_=+\/]*))?$/)
> [ "foogoobar-baz", "goobar", "baz" ]
'foogoo-bar-baz'.match(/foo([a-z0-9_=+\/-]+?)(?:-([a-z0-9_=+\/]*))?$/)
> [ "foogoo-bar-baz", "goo-bar", "baz" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a non-capturing group:

```
/foo([a-z0-9\-_=\+\/]+)(?:-(.*))?/i
```

That solves the problem of avoiding the additional capture group. However, your pattern still has the problem of including `-` as a valid character for the first string. Because of that, when you execute the pattern against "foobar-baz", the entire fragment "bar-baz" will match the first group in the pattern.

You're going to have to decide what it is you want to match; your rule is currently at odds with the result you seek. If you remove the `-` from the first group:

```
/foo([a-z0-9_=\+\/]+)(?:-(.*))?/i
```

then you get the result you say you're looking for.

Comment: I don't think it is the part that OP is having trouble with, but it is one step closer to the solution.

Comment: @nhahtdh yes I just added to the answer. It's not clear what the OP actually wants.

Comment: I think OP was quite clear about the output, though?

Comment: @nhahtdh yes true, but that `-` in the first group is problematic.